# Why does Perl complain about barewords in my Win32::OLE script?

Tags: perl, warnings, bareword

```
#___ FIND LAST ROW/COLUMN WITH DATA
my $row = $Sheet1 -> UsedRange -> Find(
     {      What => "*", 
            SearchDirection => xlPrevious,  
            SearchOrder => xlByRows
      })-> {Row};
```

Error:

```
Bareword "xlByRows" not allowed while "strict subs" in use.
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to put `use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';` at the top of your program to import the constants correctly.

Take a look at this [Perl Monks page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=153486). It seems to cover the issues you are having.

Answer (score 4):

See [CPAN docs for Win32::OLE::Const](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::OLE::Const)

You need to:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
```

Answer (score 1):

xlByRows is not a constant, you should put it in quotes. Unless it's a constant exported by the OLE object, in which case you need to import it into your namespace using Win32::OLE::Const or similar.